# Android Studio IDE | Extract member variables and methods from Java class?

Tags: java, android, class, ide, member-variables

Im new to Android Studio IDE. 
I just have a question, its is there a way to extract all member variables and methods in a java class that had been written before?
I mean suppose that I had a 6000-lines java class and it has so many member variables and methods inside, how can I have a recap of all that real quick?
Hopefully I could get some responses from you guys.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open a list of fields and methods of a class at `View -> Tool Windows -> Structure`.